# c# find string values with different permutations within an array of string

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm struggling to find a clean way to get the hard drive and memory values from an array of strings. Each string has a different permutation from the next and I have over 1000 records to get this information from.

To make it more complicated there is the reference of MAX or M-A-X which is an internal reference and I need to capture this and any values attached to it. See 3rd and 4th item in the array. In those instances, I'd need to capture 2TB HD and 1TB HD respectively.

Below is a snapshot of the data I have to get this information from.

What's the best way to tackle this?

Thanks in advance.

```
string[] arrayString = {"Desktop 1TB Hard Drive 4GB RAM",
                                "Desktop 500GB HDD 2GB Memory",
                                "Laptop MAX HDD (2TB HD) 4GB ram", //capture the MAX & 2TB HD as part of the hard drive value
                                "Desktop M-A-X HDD (1TB HD) 2GB RAM", //capture the M-A-X & 1TB HD as part of the hard drive value
                                "1000Gb HardDrive, 2gb ram - promotion",
                                "Hard Drive 100GB",
                                "Desktop MAX HDD MAX RAM",
                                "Laptop MAX HDD 2TBHD 4GBR"};

        foreach (var s in arrayString)
        {
            //get hard drive value in TB, GB, MB
            var hardDrive = "";

            //get memory/ram value in GB, MB
            var memory = "";
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to only find MAX and M-A-X values? Or want dynamic solution?

Comment: Annoyingly has to be a dynamic solution.

Comment: I guess there are a limited set to those permutatuins? I.e. The RAM would be either "Xgb ram", "Xgb memory", "Xgbr", etc. right?

Comment: There's a lot of permutations. The above is just a snapshot. It makes trying to manipulate and find the values really difficult.

Comment: I was thinking of a list of regex to match memory and a list to match hard drive, u might need a bit of trial an error (by finding the entries that didn't match any of the regexes, then modifying to capture them). But again that only works if u have a relatively small number of permutations

Answer (score 0):

Hope I can help a little.

```
foreach (var s in arrayString)
{
    var hardDrive = "";
    var memory = "";
    string[] splitString = s.Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
    foreach (var st in splitString)
    {
        //Insert all your data parsing in here, keeping in mind that you're working one string at a time
    }
}
```